# Copying table despite foreign key constraints

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

I'm trying to create a reporting database that updates itself every few hours or so from the production db. I'm using a python script and psycopg2 to do this. I'm able to copy some tables using the following code:

```
speedy_serve_cursor = speedy_serve_con.cursor()
archives_cursor = archives_con.cursor()

speedy_serve_cursor.execute('SELECT * from "TranslatableItems"')

for row in speedy_serve_cursor.fetchall():
    archives_cursor.execute('INSERT INTO "TranslatableItems" VALUES %s',(row,))

archives_con.commit()
```

This works for certain tables, but there are some with several foreign key constraints that require me to copy the parent tables first. I get the error "insert or update on table violates foreign key constraint". How can I go about find all the parent tables or copying all linked tables at once?